# Was there any meaning behind the Nijuu Neji password in TekWar?

Tags: tekwar

In TekWar, there's the following exchange where a password is used by Jake to get past Sonny's guards

> Jake was just behind the other man, a spare jacket he'd borrowed from the bedroom closet at the villa
> draped over his arm and hand,
> concealing the lazgun. He jabbed at Sands's back with the barrel.
> "Override the robot," he instructed quietly.
>
> "I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're—"
>
> "You and Sonny's other henchmen come and go all the time carrying
> weapons. So give this guard the password."
>
> "Why should I help you to—"
>
> "I wasn't kidding about having no more patience tonight. Do it, do it
> now or I'll drop you right here."
>
> After running his tongue over his lips, Sands nodded up at the robot
> and said, **"Nijuu neji."**
>
> The small square of red in the row on the robot's metal chest ceased
> flashing. "You should have identified yourselves earlier, gentlemen."
> He bowed and stepped aside. "Go right on in."

What's the meaning behind this password? Google doesn't have any obvious translation for the words or combined phrase, and to my knowledge this isn't brought up anywhere else in the book.

Comment: I have twitted at the author.

Answer (score -1):

Direct translation from japanese is "20 screws", as nijuu is 二十 and neji is [螺子「ネジ」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%9E%BA%E5%AD%90). Fitting for a robot.

Comment: It also translates phonetically to 'double rainbow' (二重 虹) and 'sandy hat' in korean. And I'm not sure whether any of them fit particularly well.

Comment: @Valorum except korean 니주네지 「niju neji」 seems to be nothing and 二重 虹 ~ 쌍무지개 「ssangmujigae」.